# Parsing a JsonObject

Tags: android, json

I have this Json model and I want to parse only one object:

```
{"CodeMsg": "Server Local Time", "server_time": "2012-03-19 19:59:30", "CodeResult": "OK"}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of libraries available to parse JSON. Two that are commonly used are:

Gson - http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Jackson - http://jackson.codehaus.org/

With both you do this:

1. Create a plain java object to represent your data - e.g. a class CodeMsg
2. Use the library to provide the JSON string/stream, and the type (CodeMsg) and an object of that type is created, with its members set according to the JSON (e.g. server_time, CodeResult, etc)

They are very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {"CodeMsg": "Server Local Time", "server_time": "2012-03-19 19:59:30", "CodeResult": "OK"};

JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(data);
and then use obj1.getJSONString('CodeMsg');
```